# run R in command line: `WARNING: unknown option '-vanilla'`

Tags: r, command-line

I'm testing running R code from command line, since I want to put it in windows scheduler.

According to `Automated data collection with R, 2015. Munzert`, I'm using this command

```
> R.exe CMD BATCH -vanilla test0.R log.txt
```

(in folder: c:\my_folder\ where test0.R is stored) `-vanilla` should tell R to not load workspace

And I got a warning in `log.txt`:

> WARNING: unknown option '-vanilla'

(and workspace was restored).

Anybody know how to fix this?

I try to fix the command line to record log, instead of using `sink` in R code, since I don't want to have to comment out `sink` when running R code interactively.

Thanks

Here's what the book says
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's `--vanilla` instead. Options come after two dashes.